# How can I repeat this query over several months in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a membership list with over 1.2M members.  People commonly subscribe, unsubscribe, and re-subscribe to the list.  Often, I find myself needing to know which users were subscribed at a particular moment in time.  I have a table called subscription_history, with this structure:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id           | native key                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id      | foreign key that joins the user table                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| change_code  |  1 or 2 for subscriptions, 4-7 for unsubscriptions   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| created_at   | date-time stamp when the change was made             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Right now, if I want to know who was subscribed at a particular date in the past (March 31, 2012 in this example), I run this query:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM
  (SELECT 
    user_id
  , MAX(created_at) AS last_change_date
  , change_code
  FROM subscriptionhistory
  WHERE DATE(created_at) <= '2012-03-31'
  GROUP BY user_id
  ) AS last
WHERE change_code IN (1,2)
```

This finds each user's last subscription action before or on the target date, then returns the user if that action was a subscription. We then use that list of users to run various other queries, such as the average lifetime sales. This system works well, but only for one date at a time. If I wanted to know the average subscriber's lifetime sales for every month of the year, I would have to run this query 12 times, manually incrementing the date in the `WHERE` statement each time.

Now I want to create a version of this that can I can use for more than a single date... so that it could give me all users subscribed in January, then February, etc., and I could run average lifetime sales for subscribers in each month.  I can't just do a `GROUP BY` for this, since someone who was a subscriber in March might have unsubscribed in April and re-subscribed in June.  I suppose I could 12 `UNION` queries ... but was hoping for something a little more elegant!

A few limiting parameters: I only have read-only access to the database; I cannot change anything about the table structure or make temporary tables.  I have to do this only in MySQL - because of the way our CRM works, I can't use Python or PHP to manipulate results.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Please let me know if I am not explaining this well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, group_concat(date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m')) as ActiveMonth from 
(SELECT user_id, created_at, change_code from Subscriptions WHERE
 change_code in (1,2) order by 1,2,3) b 
group by user_id
order by user_id, ActiveMonth desc
```

You can take the group_concat out and the group by and it should give you a row and active month for every user_id.

I created a SQLFiddle and changed the table name to subscriptions for ease of use.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b2f2/14

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Sadly, I don't understand this answer.  I definitely need lists of user_ids, rather than counts, so I tried your second example, but because there is a MAX in the SELECT but no GROUP BY, it only returns a single record.  Aside from that, I don't see how this would work... I need ALL users who were on the list on the last day of each month... not just users with activity in that month.

Comment: So, if someone joins on Jan 15, unsubs on April 15, and resubs on July 15, I need that user to return for Jan, Feb, Mar, July, and Aug ... even though the user does not have history records during some of those months.  I don't see how the example could accomplish that.  So sorry if my explanation was not clear.  Thanks again!